# linq avg on grouped counts

Tags: linq, count, group-by, average

Please consider this simple class

```
public class SEANCE 
{
    int ID_SEANCE {get;set;}
    DateTime SEA_DATE {get;set;}
}
```

It's for a fitness management app, the SEANCE class is the session table for the members.

Here's my starting query to show the number of the sessions grouped by day Hour

```
var lst = ctx.SEANCES
.GroupBy(o => o.SEA_DATE.Hour)
.Select(g => new ChartData()
{
    DT = new DateTime(2017, 01, 01, g.Key, 0, 0),
    VALUE = g.Count()
});


return lst.OrderBy(a => a.DT).ToList();
```

as you can see, it returns the total number of sessions grouped by hour.
What I want instead is the average number of sessions **by day** and **grouped by hour**, and that's where I am a little lost :p

here what i mean 
[image]

for example at 18, 1500 is corresponding to the total number of sessions at that time.

what i want instead is the average number by day

hope it make sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

`ctx.SEANCES.Count() / lst.Count()`, but that seems like database source so better to use the result:

```
var groups = ctx.SEANCES
                .GroupBy(s => s.SEA_DATE.Hour)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .Select(g => new ChartData() 
                {
                    DT = g.First().SEA_DATE, 
                    VALUE = g.Count()
                })
                .ToList();

var averageByHour = groups.Average(c => c.VALUE);

var averageByDay = groups.GroupBy(s => s.DT.Day).Average(g => g.Sum(c => c.VALUE));
```

Comment: sorry but i think that i have clicked the submit button too fast :) what i want is the average count by day and grouped by hour

Comment: @user2475096 I can't test it and there isn't enough information for a good answer, but you can try the updated answer and go from there